Getting the month difference based on three dates criteria
Here is my code I am using to find out the month difference.
loan disbursement date = 05-12-2023,
loan collection day = 1st Saturday of each month
current date
So we need to find out how many 1st Saturday falls in between the disbursement date and current date. Because on each month 1 Saturday they will collect emi.


$(document).ready(function () {
  initializeDateInputs();
  // Function to calculate attendance percentage
  function calculateAttendancePercentage() {
    var checkedCount = $('input[name="pstatus[]"]:checked').length; // Count of checked checkboxes
    var totalRowCount = $('#lcount').val(); // Total row count

    // Calculate the percentage of checked checkboxes
    var checkedPercentage = (checkedCount / totalRowCount) * 100;

    return checkedPercentage;
  }

  // Function to update submit button state based on attendance percentage
  function updateSubmitButton() {
    var attendancePercentage = calculateAttendancePercentage();

    if (attendancePercentage >= 50) {
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }

  // Initial calculation and button state update
  updateSubmitButton();

  // Event listener for attendance checkboxes change
  $('input[name="pstatus[]"]').change(function () {
    updateSubmitButton();

    var checkedPercentage = calculateAttendancePercentage();

    // Show toast messages based on attendance percentage
    if (checkedPercentage >= 50) {
      Swal.fire({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-right',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 5000,
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Scheduled Meeting',
        text: 'You have reached 50% attendance requirement. You can now submit the form.',
        customClass: {
          background: 'bg-green', // Apply bg-green class for success
        },
      });
    } else {
      Swal.fire({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-right',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 5000,
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Scheduled Meeting',
        text: 'Please ensure at least 50% attendance to submit the form!',
        customClass: {
          background: 'bg-danger', // Apply bg-green class for success
        },
      });
    }
  });

  // Calculate arrear demand when EMI date changes
  calculateArrearDemand();

  async function calculateArrearDemand() {
    const disdateValue = $("#disdate").val();
    const lrddateValue = $("#lrd").val();

    if (!disdateValue) {
      console.error("Disbursement date is not defined");
      return;
    }

    if (!lrddateValue) {
      console.error("Loan repayment day is not defined");
      return;
    }

    const disbursementDate = parseDate(disdateValue);
    const currentDate = new Date();

    if (!disbursementDate || !currentDate) {
      console.error("Invalid disbursement date or current date");
      return;
    }

    const monthDifference = calculateMonthsDifference(disbursementDate, currentDate, lrddateValue);
    
    console.log("Month difference:", monthDifference);
  }

  // Calculate the difference in months based on disbursement date, current date, and loan repayment day
  function calculateMonthsDifference(disdate, currentDate, lrddate) {
    let monthDifference = 0;
    let currentMonth = disdate.getMonth();
    let currentYear = disdate.getFullYear();
    
    while (currentYear < currentDate.getFullYear() || (currentYear === currentDate.getFullYear() && currentMonth <= currentDate.getMonth())) {
      if (containsNthDayOfMonth(currentYear, currentMonth, lrddate)) {
        monthDifference++;
      }

      currentMonth++;
      if (currentMonth > 11) {
        currentMonth = 0; // January
        currentYear++;
      }
    }

    return monthDifference;
  }

  // Check if the specified month contains the nth occurrence of the specified day
  function containsNthDayOfMonth(year, month, lrddate) {
    const [occurrenceStr, dayOfWeekStr] = lrddate.split(' ');
    const occurrence = parseInt(occurrenceStr[0], 10); // e.g., "1st" -> 1
    const dayOfWeek = getDayIndex(dayOfWeekStr); // e.g., "Saturday" -> 6

    if (isNaN(occurrence) || dayOfWeek === -1) {
      console.error("Invalid occurrence or day of week");
      return false;
    }

    let count = 0;
    for (let day = 1; day <= 31; day++) {
      const date = new Date(year, month, day);
      if (date.getMonth() !== month) break; // Stop if we've moved to the next month

      if (date.getDay() === dayOfWeek) {
        count++;
        if (count === occurrence) return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  function parseDate(dateStr) {
    if (!dateStr) {
      console.error("Invalid date string:", dateStr);
      return null;
    }

    const parts = dateStr.split('-');
    if (parts.length !== 3) {
      console.error("Invalid date format:", dateStr);
      return null;
    }

    return new Date(parts[2], parts[1] - 1, parts[0]);
  }

  function getDayIndex(dayName) {
    const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    return days.indexOf(dayName);
  }

  // Function to initialize date inputs
  function initializeDateInputs() {
    const disdateInput = document.getElementById('disdate');
    const lrddateInput = document.getElementById('lrd');

    if (!disdateInput || !lrddateInput) {
      console.error("One or more date input elements are missing");
      return;
    }

    const currentDate = new Date();
    console.log("Current date:", formatDate(currentDate));
  }

  function formatDate(date) {
    if (!date) return null;
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
    const day = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
    return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
  }

  // Form submission handling
  $('#formScheduled').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var gid = $("#gid").val();

    if (gid == "") {
      $("#gid").closest('.form-control form-control-sm').addClass('has-error');
      $("#gid").after('<p class="text-danger">Please enter group name!<br></p>');
    } else {
      $("#gid").closest('.form-control form-control-sm').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
    }

    if (gid) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "AppController/addScheduledMeeting",
        method: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
          $(".form-control form-control-sm").removeClass("has-error has-success");

          if (response.success == true) {
            Swal.fire({
              icon: "success",
              title: "Good Job!",
              text: "Meeting scheduled Successfully",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 5000,
            });
            window.location.reload();
          } else {
            Swal.fire({
              icon: "error",
              title: "Oops...",
              text: "An error occurred. Please try again later.",
              showConfirmButton: false,
              timer: 5000,
            });
          }
        },
        error: function () {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: "error",
            title: "Oops...",
            text: "An error occurred. Please try again later.",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 5000,
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return false;
  });
});




You might have forgotten to ask a question. Is your current code working? If not what are the current results and what are the expected results? And please also provide some example with expected results ...

If you need to use jargon in your question ("emi") please define it, so that readers can understand your question. I agree that this question still needs a specific problem statement.

I am assuming you are looking for the number of first saturdays of the months between two dates.
When working with time, it is best to use an existing library (because time is a programmers worst enemy). I would choose moment and write a function like this:
import moment from 'moment'
import assert from 'node:assert/strict'

function diff(date, to) {
    const d = moment(date);
    const now = to ? moment(to) : moment();
    const start = moment.min(d, now).startOf('day');
    const end = moment.max(d, now).startOf('day');

    // Set start to the first saturday of the next month,
    // if it is already past the first saturday of the current month
    if (start > moment(start).date(1).day(6)) {
        start.add(1, 'month').date(1).day(6);
    }

    let num = 0;
    while (start < end) {
        num++;       
        start.add(1, 'month').date(1).day(6); // Next first saturday
    }
    return num
}

assert.equal(diff(new Date("2024-01-20"), new Date("2024-06-26")), 5);
assert.equal(diff(new Date("2024-01-06"), new Date("2024-06-26")), 6);
//                         ^first saturday
assert.equal(diff(new Date("2024-01-06"), new Date("2024-06-01")), 5); // Notice how the end date is exclusive
//                         ^first saturday         ^first saturday

Functionality of the used functions:

.date(1): Sets the day of the month to the first (ref)
.day(6): Sets the date to the next (or current) saturday (ref)
.add(1, 'month'): Adds 1 month to the date (ref)

